# Trouble obtaining data using genfromtxt

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Initial height', param[4]],
        ['Exponential decay constant', param[1]],
        ['Angular frequency', param[2]],
        ['Phi offset', param[3]],
        ['The amplitude', param[0]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Variable', 'Value'])
print(df)

writePath = '/Users/harryhat/Desktop/Droplet Experiment/Variables/Trial/water-3 variables.txt'
with open(writePath, 'w') as f:
    f.write(
        df.to_string(header = False, index = False)
    )

data = np.genfromtxt(writePath, usecols=2)
```

from which I want to obtain the second column as save it as data. However when I try to use this the second parameter comes up as nan but I don't know why. Attached is the console showing what type it is and that value that it is. Does anyone know why im getting nan for that value? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: default load dtype is float.  `nan` appears when the cell isn't a valid number.  Show the csv file.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to python, but what do you mean. Do you want to know how I calculated param or do you want a picture of the text file which the pandas data frame was saved to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your write:

```
    In [31]: with open('tst1.csv', 'w') as f:
    ...:     f.write(
    ...:         df.to_string(header = False, index = False)
    ...:     )
    ...: 


In [33]: cat tst1.csv
             Initial height  0.601793
 Exponential decay constant  0.612753
          Angular frequency  0.109519
                 Phi offset  0.301704
              The amplitude  0.649477

In [34]: np.genfromtxt('tst1.csv', usecols=2)
Out[34]: array([0.601793,      nan, 0.109519, 0.301704, 0.649477])
```

The default delimiter is white space.  The problem line has 4 fields:

```
In [35]: np.genfromtxt('tst1.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-35-307e4ac22394>", line 1, in <module>
    np.genfromtxt('tst1.csv')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 2080, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #2 (got 4 columns instead of 3)
```

If instead I use

```
In [37]: df.to_csv('tst.csv')

In [38]: cat tst.csv
,Variable,Value
0,Initial height,0.6017927371181283
1,Exponential decay constant,0.6127532376900192
2,Angular frequency,0.109519476902042
3,Phi offset,0.3017037244796229
4,The amplitude,0.6494771015260451
```

This loads col 2 just fine - the initial `nan` is the header, which I could skip:

```
In [39]: np.genfromtxt('tst.csv',delimiter=',', usecols=2)
Out[39]: 
array([       nan, 0.60179274, 0.61275324, 0.10951948, 0.30170372,
       0.6494771 ])
```

`genfromtxt` has a lot of parameters, though not as many as `to_csv`.

Comment: ah ok so so when it converts it to a text file the string gets split up into individual words as in the csv the whole phrase is a string? Thank you very much, that's cleared it up!